# How to Split Maven project into different modules?

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-2, project-structure

I am completely newbie to Maven, I've a requirement to split my project into four different projects like

1. web project
2. model project
3. DAOs project
4. Tests project

Finally packaging should be single war file only for deployment.
Please tell me the best way to do that, using Spring 3.2 + Hibernate + Eclipse Juno.

Please tell me the procedure and give me that sample application link. Please explain.

And finally I don't know what exactly difference between Maven and Maven 2.

Comment: What kind of purpose does the `Tests project`have? Integration tests ?

Comment: Tests project having integration test cases by writing spring mvc test cases

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried to look into this: 
http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html

It contains an example that I think can help you to get started i.e. it describes multi module projects. You can then use it as a base reference for your case.

There is some article that describes between Maven 1 and Maven 2 here: 
http://community.scmgalaxy.com/blog/view/19418

Comment: Forget Maven 1. We have maven 3 and 3.1

Answer (score 0):

The structure should look like this:

```
+-- root (pom.xml)
     +-- web-project
     +-- model-project
     +-- dao-project
     +-- test-project
```

This means having `root` checked into SVN (trunk) or Git (master) as the root of the project structure which will include all other sub folders. You have to use a multi-module build which exactly represents your needs. If you have dependencies on the other modules (model, dao) in your web project it will be packaged automatically into the war file.

The docs like [sonatype](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule-sect-simple-web.html) is a good start. But you have to start reading the docs yourself.

Comment: Thanx for that link, I ll go through that pages.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to cover your second concern:

> I don't know what exactly difference between Maven and Maven 2

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven#History),

> Maven, created by Takari's Jason van Zyl, began as a subproject of Apache Turbine in 2002. In 2003, it was voted on and accepted as a top level Apache Software Foundation project. In July 2004, Maven's release was the critical first milestone, v1.0. Maven 2 was declared v2.0 in October 2005 after about six months in beta cycles. Maven 3.0 was released in October 2010 being mostly backwards compatible with Maven 2.

Today in 2018, Maven and Maven 2 reached their end of life and are no longer supported -- [End Of Life Apache Maven 2.x](https://maven.apache.org/maven-2.x-eol.html). Apache Maven 3.5.3 is the latest release and recommended version for all users -- [check new versions here](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi).